# How to numerically solve this non-standard Green's function using mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

$$\left(u(1-u^2)\frac{d^2}{du^2}-(u^2+1)\frac{d}{du}-\frac{au}{(1-u^2)}-\frac{bu^3}{(1-u^2)}+c\right)G(u,u')=mu^2\delta(u-u'),$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $m$ are constants, $u\in(-1,1)$ and the boundary conditions are $G(u,u')\rightarrow 0$ for $u=\pm 1$.
 Thank you very much!

The constants are proper input parameters. Can mathematica read Dirac delta functions directly? I particularly want to know how to reformulate this question so that it is available to numerically solve this equation.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I am very sorry, I corrected my question. Though, it is still not a standard Green's function.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, Thank you for your remind. I added the boundary conditions.

Comment: You can use `DiracDelta[]` in the expression. This however, is only handled correctly by `DSolve`, which is limited to analytically solvable differential equations. Possibly related question with good hints by Leonid Shifrin how to tackle this kind of problem: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61176/using-ndsolve-to-solve-a-pde-with-a-dirac-delta-function

Comment: Here's one idea (don't know if it will work nicely or not): for each $u'$, solve the differential equation to the right and left of $u'$ (so that the delta function is actually zero) using `NDSolve`, then match the two functions at $u'$ with a Wronskian.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke That's very useful information. Thanks!

Comment: @march Yes, I know the Wronskian in the analytical method. But in numerical method, there are no two different explicit solutions, hence the Wronskian can not be defined properly.

Comment: Perhaps I'm totally misremembering how this works (it's been a while), but what about if you used `ParametricNDSolve`? That way, you can solve the problem for $u_{<}$ that matches the left boundary condition with the right boundary condition as a parameter, and the corresponding problem for $u_{>}$ with the left boundary condition as a parameter, and then vary that parameter until the Wronskian matches?

Comment: @march:  I tried that approach myself yesterday.  Unfortunately, the ODE in question has regular singular points at the boundary $u = \pm 1$, which Mathematica really doesn't like.  I suspect you could do a power-series expansion about these points, which would allow you to move the boundary to $\pm (1 - \epsilon)$;  but I haven't tried it out myself.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, Thank you very much. I think we can replace the boundary condition appeared in the question by $G= 0$ at, say $u=\pm 0.999999$. But I really want to know how did you handle the Dirac delta function?

Comment: By integrating the ODE twice in a small region about $u'$, we find that $G$ is continuous at $u'$ and that its derivative has a discontinuous change of $m u' / (1 - {u'}^2)$ at $u'$.  This can be viewed as a boundary condition between the solutions in $[-1,u')$ and $(u',+1]$.  You can use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve for $G$ in each of these regions in terms of some parameters (either the value of $G'$ at the boundaries, or the value of $G$ at $u'$).  Finally, you use `FindRoot` to try to vary your parameter(s) so that your two solutions satisfy the correct boundary conditions at $u'$.

Comment: When I tried this on a similar equation, I ran into problems with the values at $u'$ being too sensitive to the values at $\pm 1$.  If this happens to you, you could try playing around with the `Method` settings in `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Perhaps things have advanced since you last tried them: `ListLinePlot@NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == y[x] + DiracDelta[x - 1], y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2}]` --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/QdR3j.png (V10.4.1, but it works in V9.0.1, too)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Cool! Nice to see it working in `NDSolve`, too now!